# Where to save users comments of an item?

Tags: mysql, comments

Basically I have a web app which it contains items and the people can comment on it and tell what they think about it. just like youtube videos or any other similar website.

**Question**
Where is the best place to save these comments. Do I Create a table in MySql database and save it there or do I save it in a `.txt` file and then save the location of the file on the database. I would really appreciate if someone tell me which is good from performance perspective or is there any alternative better way.

Much appreciations.

Answer (score 1):

Save the comments directly in database.

- Adding a comment in file and saving the path in database is not good you are adding extra work.
- Reading from database is easy and more professional as every where it is in use. In YouTube as well.
- There is chance someone delete your file and you will lose your data.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the database. They were build to replace the unpleasant storage of data in flatfiles also for performance reason.

Comment: so in that case I might need to just create one table for all items comments, right? if so what if it overflowed 100000+ comments.

Comment: Since the database will have indexes this amount wouldn't be a problem. You would automatically have a index on `item_id` within your comments table as you define it as a foreign key to the items table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the comments in the database. It is easier to query and sort the comment later on. Despite save as .txt, it is safer to save it in database.